# Convertir diferencia entre fechas en formato hora:minutos en Redshift

Tags: sql

Estoy rescatando una serie de estadísticas de Amazon Redshift con una consulta SQL de la siguiente manera:

```
`select a.query as idquery,a.starttime as inicio,a.endtime as 
fin,datediff(ms,inicio,fin) as tiempototal,
datediff(ms,queue_start_time,queue_end_time) as tiempo_total_cola 
from stl_query a, stl_wlm_query b where a.query=b.query and tiempototal >= 
14400000 order by idquery`
```

El campo `tiempototal` me devuelve un valor en ms: 33084769 y me gustaría obtenerlo en formato HH:MM:SS

¿Cómo puedo convertir en la misma consulta `tiempototal`y `tiempo_total_cola` en formato HH:MM:SS? Es decir, necesito sacar la duración en horas y minutos.

Comment: ¿Algo así? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367603/mysql-convert-int-to-datetime

Comment: He probado a utilizar from_unixtime, pero en Redshift no existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes con un poco de aritmética

```
select floor(33084769 / 86400000)           as dias,
       mod(floor(33084769 / 3600000), 24)   as horas,
       mod(floor(33084769 / 60000), 60)     as mins,
       mod(floor(33084769 / 1000), 60)      as seg

dias horas mins  seg
---- ----- ----- -----
0,00 9,00  11,00 24,00
```

Cada valor por el cual divides es la cantidad de millisegundos de un día, hora, minutos y segundos.

Comment: Me lanza el siguiente error:

`42883: operator does not exist: double precision % integer`

Comment: Hola @lk2_89, no sabía, en redshift `%` modulo es `MOD` prueba mi última edición

Comment: Gracias @Patricio Moracho. Estoy intentándolo con el último formato, pero me sigue dando error. 

Estoy probando esto: `select query as idquery, exec_start_time as inicioproceso, exec_end_time as finproceso, datediff(ms,inicioproceso,finproceso) as tiempototal,
mod(floor(tiempototal/3600000),24) as horas
from stl_wlm_query where tiempototal >= 14400000 order by idquery` y me lanza el siguiente error: `42883: function mod(double precision, integer) does not exist`

Comment: El error pareciera indicar que estás invocando a la función `mod()` con parámetros diferentes a `double` el primero e `int` el segundo. Podrías verificarlo?

Comment: Si, estaba pasándole parámetros distintos. 

Lo he solucionado haciendo un casteo previo: `mod(cast(floor(tiempototal/3600000) as integer),24)`